# when hitting enter in text box the value disappearing

Tags: c#

I wish to accept maximum two digits to my text box I used this code.

```
if(textbox1.textlength==1)            
{
    this.selectNextcontrol((control)sender,true,true,true,true); 
}
```

now the problem is that the text box also accept single value like 6, it is accepting but when I hit enter after placing 6 the value disappearing.

Comment: Post the code of the `selectNextcontrol` method also

Comment: Please provide a bit more context, and which platform you're using (WinForms, WPF, ASPNet, ...). Also, are you sure this is c#, as your casing (e.g. "textlength") is not standard, ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.textlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: windows form@YvesSchelpe

Answer (score 0):

You can set maximum length property of textbox to 2.